# Write a json file from list

Tags: python, json

I have the following list data I want to save in a json file to be access later:

```
data = [{"nomineesWidgetModel":{"title":"","description":"",  
"refMarker":"ev_nom","eventEditionSummary":{"awards":[{"awardName":"Oscar","trivia":[]}]}}}]
```

**If saved as txt:**

```
for item in data:
    with open('./data/awards.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(', '.join(str(item) for item in data))

Output:
{"nomineesWidgetModel":{"title":"","description":"","refMarker":"ev_nom", 
 "eventEditionSummary":{"awards":[{"awardName":"Oscar","trivia":[]}]}}}
```

But I get an error when opening the file later in Jupyter Notebook

**If save as json**

```
for item in data:
    with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(item, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

Output with extra backslash:
"{\"nomineesWidgetModel\":{\"title\":\"\",\"description\":\"\",\"refMarker\":\"ev_nom\", 
 \"eventEditionSummary\":{\"awards\":[{\"awardName\":\"Oscar\",\"trivia\":[],}]}}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this without having to import the file and replace the extra slashes?

Comment: I think the program is behaving as expected. That list isn’t a list of dictionaries, it’s a list of strings, which is probably why they’re getting escaped. In any case, I’m pretty sure you can just `json.dump()` the entire thing, no need to iterate. Other general tip, you can move the loop inside the context manager for the file. Can you share the error you’re getting when opening it in a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: My comment jumps around a bit, but the important thing here to actually solve the issue is to just write `json.dump(data)` to file. Let me know if that works though, I’m not entirely certain. I will try writing a proper answer with a better explanation later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `json` as usual:

```
import json

data = [{"nomineesWidgetModel":{"title":"","description":"", "refMarker":"ev_nom","eventEditionSummary":{"awards":[{"awardName":"Oscar","trivia":[]}]}}}]

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alexander explanation above, I was able to save the content I was scraping in a dict, and not a list, and then save as json while iterating the pages with:

```
with open('data.json', 'a') as file:
            json.dump(data, file, indent=1)
```